# What is the process to create a .exe file for a .NET MAUI Blazor application?

Tags: blazor, maui, maui-blazor, maui-windows

I have made a .NET MAUI application using Blazor. And I want to export my application to share with my client. So I want to give them an .exe file with the app to run in windows. How can I do it?
I'm using VS 22

I tried to publish the app but the file is in other extension file type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maui is deployed as an MSIX file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/overview), not as an exe. So that it can install needed dependencies:

> .NET MAUI currently only allows publishing an MSIX package. You can't yet publish a Windows executable file for distribution.

Note that an MSIX file is always an "install" action. It isn't currently possible to deploy something that can be run without installation.